# Как отключить Autorotate через скрипт в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, мобильная-разработка

Допустим так для облегчения:

```
if(autorotate){включаем автоповорот, 
или как-нибудь поставить галочки на
Landscape в player settings}
else галочки убираем с landscape.
```

Я прикрепил созданный скрипт ScreenOrient в MainCamera.

```
void Update 
 { 
   if( Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.FaceUp)
 { //вот тут хочу сделать только портретную ориентацию 
  //deviceOrientation = Portrait. Но не понимаю как. 
 } 
}
```

Т.е. когда телефон положить экраном вверх, переключалось в Портретный. Главное в скрипте как вынужденно повернуть экран мне надо знать. Спасибо. И извиняюсь, если непонятно объяснил, не описал.

Comment: Вы сами хоть пытались найти ответ? Гугл выдаёт верный ответ первой же ссылкой.

Comment: Если вы про ScreenOrientatio.Landscape и тд, то он не работает

Comment: Что значит «не работает»? Приведите код, опишите проблему.

Comment: Я прикрепил созданный скрипт ScreenOrient в MainCamera.
void Update{
    if( Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.FaceUp){
    //вот тут хочу сделать только портретную ориентацию
    //deviceOrientation = Portrait. Но не понимаю как.
    }
 }
Т.е. когда телефон положить экраном вверх, переключалось в Портретный. Главное в скрипте как вынужденно повернуть экран мне надо знать. Спасибо. И извиняюсь, если непонятно объяснил, не описал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я и указал в комментариях: этот вопрос решается путем заглядывания в документацию.

[**Screen.orientation**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-orientation.html)

> Specifies logical orientation of the screen.
>
> Default value is taken from the 'Default Orientation' in Player
>   Settings.

**[ScreenOrientation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenOrientation.html)**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
void Update() {
    if(Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.FaceUp) {
        Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
    }
}
```

---

Думаю, очевидно, что данный код будет работать только в билде на смартфонах, редактор или Unity Remote не подойдут.